# В каких языках есть undefined?

Tags: android, javascript, разработка-игр

Видел игрушку под андроид и ios. Когда быстро листаешь карту - временно появляется undefined вместо значений. Интересует кроссплатформенная технология которую используют в этой игре(Войны спарты).
На уме только JS и AS

Всё, свой вопрос решил, это GLES2(AndEngine).
Всем спасибо.

Comment: Давайте apk. Со 99.99% вероятностью определю технологию

Comment: http://rghost.ru/46347011 Вот APK

Comment: В вашем случае это дело рук какого-то движка вроде unity. Но на него не похоже. Игра 2D?

Comment: Сложно сказать, вроде 3D, но ракурс у объектов только 1. Так что 2D  
скрин http://s.appleinsider.ru/2013/05/IMG_6318.jpeg

Comment: Ну может тогда corona с lua, не знаю. Впрочем ссылаясь на ответ @VladD это должен быть либо js, либо lua. Опять же, не в чистом виде, а изменённые движком (вспомните доп функции js -a в unity)

Comment: Стал ковыряться в APK, нашел xml-ки для collada (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA)

Comment: Всё, свой вопрос решил, это GLES2(AndEngine). Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

в любом языке можно выводить такое.

```
if(empty($var)){
  print('undefined');
}
```

Вряд ли по этому слову вы сможете определить язык.

P.S. более правильный и универсальный способ - try-catch блок с попыткой обратиться к значению.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте для начала выясним, что же такое `undefined` в Javascript. Из *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide*:

> You might consider undefined to represent a system-level, unexpected, or error-like absence of value and null to represent program-level, normal, or expected absence of value.

Таким образом, undefined означает *ошибочное*, непредусмотренное отсутствие значения.

Концепция, схожая с undefined, есть в большом количестве языков. Однако, другие языки часто не разделяют *ошибочное* и *намеренное* отсутствие значения.

В языках, ведущих своё происхождение от Алгола (или пользующихся его идеями), есть концепция [null reference/pointer](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3186), которая имеет схожую семантику: отсутствие значения. (Например: Pascal, C, Objective C, C++, Java, C#, Python.) Здесь намеренное отсутствие значения представляется как null (NULL, nil, etc.)

Ошибочное отсутствие значения, однако, в C и унаследовавшем эту концепцию C++ (а также, судя по всему, в других небезопасных языках) представляется по существу [случайным значением указателя](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WildPointer). В отличие от Javascript, такое значение невозможно отловить, оставаясь в рамках языка, так как обращение к нему уже есть [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behaviour).

В других языках (Java, C#) компилятор контролирует значения указателей, и неинициализированное значение нельзя наблюдать (без выхода за рамки языка). Например, массивы указателей инициализируются значением `null`. Таким образом, компилятор устраняет возможность *ошибочного* отсутствия значения, заменяя её на *преднамернное* отсутствие значения (и потенциально жертвуя частью производительности программы).

Ещё один заслуживающий внимания язык, содержащий концепцию отсутствующего значения — SQL. В нём базовый тип данных может быть использован как NULLABLE, то есть, быть дополнен искусственным значением NULL, означающим отсутствие данных. Здесь, однако, NULL означает *намеренное* отсутствие данных, а *непреднамеренное* отсутствие данных выражается, судя по всему, отсутствием строки в таблице.

---

То, с чем вы столкнулись — особенности *вывода* undefined-значения. В принципе, правильно написанная программа **никогда** не должна пытаться вывести ошибочно неинициализированное значение. Javascript в этих случаях использует *строку* `"undefined"`, другие языки обычно используют другие строки (`0`, `null` etc.). Это, однако, лишь внешнее различие.

Насколько я знаю, конкретно строку "undefined" использует лишь Javascript и основанные на нём языки.

Comment: Как раз речь и идет, о том в каких языках и технологиях есть вывод несуществующего значения в виде undefined(если кастануть в string) по умолчанию

Comment: @ErrorMan: дополнил.

Comment: То есть, по вашему мнению, если в этой программе нет написанного обработчика несуществующих значений, то это скорее всего JS?

Comment: @ErrorMan, если нету специального обработчика, что, к слову, маловероятно, то да, скорее всего это JavaScript.

Учитывая то, что это 2.5d игра, это вполне вероятно.

Comment: Всё, свой вопрос решил, это GLES2(AndEngine). Всем спасибо.